# Where should I store a site sitewide configuration setting for a Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails app and from the admin section of the site I'd like to be able to enable / disable certain settings such as serving ads or embedding of Google Analytics tracking code.

Is there a best practice for this in Rails?  One thought was creating a settings table and storing values in it.

Comment: How will you be rendering the HTML?

Comment: It sounds like you're editing run-time settings, which probably belong in a database table.

Comment: Sam, I was thinking the HTML would be rendered in the application layout file probably using a custom helper method.

Comment: The setting you mentioned, GA tracking code, is there only one per the whole application? Then a configuration file would be fine. If it is configurable across multiple users in the app (such as a hosted CMS), then you definitely want a database column for that field.

Answer (score 3):

If you're not going for run-time configuration, then you might use something like rbates' nifty-config generator: http://github.com/ryanb/nifty-generators

I've used it for simple, build-time configuration settings. So, for instance, when storing payment gateway credentials for an ecommerce site, my load_gateway_config.yml looks like this:

```
require 'ostruct'

raw_config = File.read(Rails.root + "config/gateway_config.yml")
GATEWAY_CONFIG = YAML.load(raw_config)[Rails.env].symbolize_keys

#allow dot notation access
GatewayConfig = OpenStruct.new(GATEWAY_CONFIG)
```

Then, to grab a setting from your config file, you'll call something like

```
GatewayConfig.username
```

Another option is the [configuration gem](https://github.com/ahoward/configuration) which gives you similar dot notation usage, but also more advanced options like setting default values, and the config file is Ruby instead of YAML.

Answer (score 1):

I would store this information in a database unless you don't have access to one.  If you do not have access to a database, you could store the file in the config folder.

Here is example controller code for reading from and writing to a config file.

```
def featured_specials
  @featured_specials = YAML::load_file("#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/featured_specials.yml")
end

def save_featured_specials
  config_file = "#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/featured_specials.yml"
  File.new(config_file, "w") unless File.exist?(config_file)
  File.open(config_file, "w") do |f|
    f.write(params['formvars'].to_yaml)
  end
  flash[:notice] = 'Featured Specials have been saved.'
  redirect_to :action => 'featured_specials'
end
```

NOTE: this code could be cleaned up quite a bit, but should serve as a decent example.

Answer (score 0):

You can store your config in the `config/` directory. I know a few applications that store their configs in that directory. (e.g. `teambox.yml` in [Teambox](http://github.com/teambox/teambox)).

Answer (score 0):

I already upvoted a different answer, but for a quick-and-dirty way you can drop a class variable in environment.rb, after the block of initializer code.